# Push notifications COURSE_ROSTER_CHANGES not received

Tags: google-classroom

We've been building out a sync functionality with Classroom and we are receiving all the class notifications for course work changes but nothing happens after registering for notifications on COURSE_ROSTER_CHANGES.

I get a registration ID and no errors when creating the registration and I am the owner of the classes in Google Classroom. Are there any other known permissions or steps that would be preventing me from receiving these?

Thank you

Comment: Check if your Google Cloud PubSub topic has permissions for classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com as Pub/Sub Publisher.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue has been reported on Google Classroom's Issue Tracker, which you can find [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/113070428). Feel free to add to the conversation so that the issue can be properly triaged.